# Homology and semidirect products

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra

If $G=N\rtimes H$ what is the relation between the second integral homology groups (Schur multipliers) of $G,N$ and $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural map $H_2(G) \rightarrow H_2(H)$ is surjective for a split extension. Apart from that, you cannot say anything very definitive. There is a natural map $H_2(N) \rightarrow H_2(G)$, but that is not usually injective. Also, the image of that map is not in general equal to the kernel of $H_2(G) \rightarrow H_2(H)$. There is another section of $H_2(G)$ coming (roughly) from commutators in $[N,H]$.

The Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre Spectral Sequence provides a theoretical background for all of this, but it does not necessarily help with calculations in specific examples.

Of course, for the direct product, $G = N \times H$, we have $H_2(G) \cong H_2(N) \oplus H_2(H) \oplus (N \otimes H)$.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate what is a tensor product $N\otimes H$ of two groups?

Comment: It's the tensor product over ${\mathbb Z}$ of their abelianizations $N/[N,N]$ and $H/[H,H]$ regarded as ${\mathbb Z}$-modules. There is a more complicated nonabelian tensor product, but that is not the meaning here.